# Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected Token < on div?

Tags: syntax

I've been checking the javascript console and found the following error("Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected Token <") on this line of code: 
`<div class="float-clear"></div>`

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, I used the same exact command on different sections of the webpage. Is there something really simple that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

That's valid HTML, but it is not valid javascript.

So if you put it inside of a `<script>…</script>` section, it will be a syntax error.

Comment: Hmm... it's so odd, while it wasn't inside of a <script> (I triple checked), putting a </script> right before the code fixed it!